# ask ghostscript to release file after runtime error

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I am using Ghostscript to diplay my drawings as I work on them.  If there is an error in my code, after `(myfile.ps)run`, I find that `myfile.ps` is read only.  How can I ask Ghostscript to release this file?

Comment: How do you mean, readonly? Before start of gs `ls -l myfile.ps` shows like `rw-rw-r--` and in your described case it looks like `r--r--r--` ? That sounds unlikely. You might mean that it's not writeable by another application because gs has the file open (for reading). I can't reproduce it here, what gs version are you using? Other potentially interesting details?

Comment: @StefanHegny You are correct: the file attributes are unchanged.  I'm on Windows 10.  Apparently Ghostscript requests a lock on the file when I `run` it.  The lock is in place when Ghostscript displays the drawing (i.e., at `showpage`).  The lock is released when the GhostScript finishes interpreting the file.  But it there is a runtime error, the file remains locked.  I would like a command at the Ghostscript command line to release this lock.

Comment: As far as I see, quitting gs seems to be the only option. The file object is on the execution stack and seems to stay there when an error occurs. But the execution stack can not be modified (except exiting from loops e.g.) - I would suggest to check the original ghostscript site/buglist/forum

Comment: OTOH, you might just try entering `stop`, worth a try

Comment: @StefanHegny Unfortunately, `stop` does not work.

Comment: You either need to run Ghostscript in job server mode, or wrap your 'run' in a save/restore pair, or run it using 'stopped'. Plenty of alternatives to shoose from.

Comment: The suggestion from @KenS sounds good if you have the chance to wrap the run call inside `stopped`

Comment: @KenS Using `save` and `restore` works.  Thanks.  But if you meant by using `stopped` something like `(myfile.ps) (r) file cvx stopped`, that does not work.  After `stop` the file is still locked.  Is this a bug?  I'd love further insight, but in any case, thanks for a solution (which I would accept as an answer).

Comment: Probably not a bug, its hard to be sure when dealing with error handling. As long as you have a solution I'd stick with that.